# Rewrite rule with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Need a little help with rewrite rule.
How do I redirect an url with query to another url with query?
Example:

```
http://example.com/prject/test.php?key=1
```

redirect to

```
http://example.com/prject/test.php?id=1
```

Also

```
http://example.com/prject/file2.php?key=1
```

to

```
http://example.com/prject/file2.php?arg=1
```

.htaccess file is located in /project/ directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `/project/.htaccess` file, insert the following:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

# Redirect test.php?key=<number> to test.php?id=<number>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^test.php$ test.php?id=%1 [R,L]

# Redirect file2.php?key=<number> to file2.php?arg=<number>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^file2.php$ test.php?arg=%1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://example2.com/prject/test.php?key=%1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, But what if I want to redirect another url http://example.com/prject/file2.php?key=1 to http://example.com/prject/file2.php?key=1. 

Also, is it possible to remove the domain name from the rule?

Comment: Change **test.php** to **file2.php** in the last line to redirect "example.com/foo/file2.php?key=1 **to** "example2.com/foo/file2.php?key=1

.
If its a Remote redirect (Redirecting a.com to b.com) then you must put the scheme and hostname in rewrite target.

Comment: No, it's same domain. I have both test.php and file2.php file in the same directory and I need both of those redirect working. If I use your rule, then http://example.com/prject/file2.php?key=1 is being redirected to http://example.com/prject/test.php?id=1. But I want it redirected to http://example.com/prject/file2.php?arg=1. ie same file with different arg name.